# How to make a dictionary with values as tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I'm new to this site and to python. I need some help with my code. So Basically I have a text file, and the text looks like this

```
Achernar                    140       0.46 
Acrux-AB                    325        0.8 
Adhara                      405        1.5
```

I am trying to make it into a dictionary. Where the name is the key and the numbers are values. But the values need to be tuples and I don't know how to do that. I tried a few things and I think this is the closest I'm going to get but it still doesn't work. I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)"

```
def starSetup():
    dictStar= {}
    with open('file.txt','r') as i:
        for line in i:
            key, val, val2 = line.strip()
            dictStar[key].append(val,val2)
        print (dictStar)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `dictStar[key] = (val, val2)`?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: it'll probably never even make it to that line, because of the missing `split`.

Answer (score 3):

It should be as follows:

```
 key, val, val2 = line.strip().split() # forgot about split
 dictStar[key] = (val,val2)    # no need for append.
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to `.strip` before you `.split` as `.split` with no arguments will strip by default.  `'   foo bar baz   '.split()` -> `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`